# How to deal with questions for which the correct answer is simply "no"?

Tags: support, questions, close-reasons

I encountered [How can I set Dkim in phpmailer?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/97793/16495) recently. The correct answer is simply:

> You can't.

Oh, of course I might quote some parts of [feature request on Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/1358446) and describe with detail why it was moved from 6 to 7 branch, but it really looks like a material for commentary more than an answer. On the other hand, question seems legit, if not of high quality. No close reason really really fits.

So what should I do when I see questions like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will vary by question, but "no" answers are perfectly acceptable.   Explain why it can't be done. Suggest alternate solutions. If possible, outline how a patch could be done.

Comment: OK, did so. Just wanted to make sure.